# Pre-mined (fully minted) token ICO

Tags: erc-20, ico

My token is fully minted and the contract is already deployed and the full amount has been distributed to several wallets.

I want to do a crowdsale for my tokens and I want to know how the best way to automatically transfer the tokens from my ICO contract to the wallet of the payer. Shall I store the tokens on the ICO contract address? How can I transfer the tokens from my ICO contract to the contract of the payer? Any examples as all I can find are mintable token contracts.